# Android Studio emulator suddenly start being very slow

Tags: android, android-emulator

The emulator was work very well , it was only take litile time to start but after that it's being fast , but suddenly the emulator start being extremely slow ( on startup and even after start is finish ) , i've tried to delete the AVD and make new one but same !

My AVD:

```
Name: Pixel_XL_API_24

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\Users\MrLibya\.android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_24.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 24)

Skin: pixel_xl

SD Card: C:\Users\MrLibya\.android\avd\Pixel_XL_API_24.avd\sdcard.img

hw.dPad: no

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: pixel_xl

vm.heapSize: 256

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 24

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-24\google_apis\x86\

tag.id: google_apis

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: emulated

hw.mainKeys: no

AvdId: Pixel_XL_API_24

hw.camera.front: emulated

hw.lcd.density: 560

avd.ini.displayname: Pixel XL API 24

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.device.hash2: MD5:9b564b60b1aebee32c73ded9daa1e620

hw.ramSize: 1024

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.cpu.ncore: 1

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Comment: Same here. It was working great last week. This week, I open it and it's taking forever to startup and also, opening apps is unbearably slow. In many cases, the emulator craps out and asks me if I want to wait on the app or close it. Eventually the entire emulator will crash and shut down if I try to continue using it.